# Search engine algorithm in Java?

Tags: java, search-engine, information-retrieval

Ok i am really new to this site, i think it has just been 2 hours so it would take a while for me to get used to the site and ask questions that do not go against the guidelines.

All i am trying to do is implement a small search engine, its not homework or work that i am going to get paid for just learning.

The serch engine would have a simple user interface for the user to ask questions and for results to be displayed.

This results would obviously need to be organised it would need to display the number of results it found and the most relevant results would be displayed on top
It would also have links to the material it found.
I have some expereince in java and therefore i need an algorithm to implement this.

There is a million different search engines some in java some in php and other languages however they have already been implemented and i need to start from scratch implementing this algorithm.

I bought a book just for this purpose its called "Introduction to Algorithms" but that does not help as much as i thougth it would.
I need some guides in java, a menu of what i need to do in the form of code.

If anyone could help, i would be very grateful.
Thanks

Comment: Your question is much too broad. Implementing a search engine is a very big topic/subject, with lots of different ways of going about it depending on your specific needs. You already have all the info you need to get started (books, reference implementations, and existing search engines to mimick (and use to find resources about the topic)). Just start planning/coding. If you hit a wall with the coding part, you can come back here with the specific code issue.

Comment: As in, a web search engine? Or for searching a file system or database that you have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the library [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html), which is a mature java based information retrieval system.

You will have to create an [IndexWriter](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html), and use it to [index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28search_engine%29) your collection of documents.

Then, you should search for a document, using an [IndexSearcher](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html). Please read the documentation, since probably all you need is already built.

If you want to implement it from scratch, I'd suggest first reading about [Information Retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval). A good source to start with will be [Introduction to Information Retrieval](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/pdf/irbookonlinereading.pdf)

Comment: I am thinking about a file system

Comment: @james: I do not follow, please explain your comment.

Comment: I meant to saying that i am thinking of implementing search engine to search for files.

Comment: @james: If you have a specific locations these files [i.e. a specific drive/directory/directories], you will just need to index them as I mentioned, look at the [tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_4_0/gettingstarted.html#Getting%20Started) and understand how it works. If your files are scattered on-line, you will also need to use a [Web Crawler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler) to first find these files.

Comment: as programmer if someone asked you to implement a search engine what would be the starting point for you, i mean what would be the first thing you would do, a diagram? can you suggest any material, how would you design a search engine?

Comment: @james: I would first read about Information Retrieval, and Lucene, as I suggested. You should first know what capabilities you can use without re-inventing the wheel, I think after you do some research, and understand how a search engine works and which libraries [Lucene] can help you out, it will be much more clear for you. If I were you, I'd first read some theory [from the book I suggested], then read what Lucene offers, and only when I am done with that: I'd start designing and coding.

Comment: ,you will regret helping me because i ask so many question, but i hope you dont mind. What about a search engine guided by user queries, that could analyse a set of given documents. Would this be easier for me.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean 'guided by user queries?'. in Lucene, when searching for a query, using an IndexSearcher, you are searching for a String. This String is for you [the programmer] to decide, and you can send the user input as this String.

Comment: Nothing thanks again, i think i would just waste your time if i ask questions without going through your material first. Thanks again